# Amount Value Truncation in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, rounding

In my app, i have an amount field. It should accept only 6 digits BEFORE decimal point and any number of digits AFTER decimal point which will be rounded off to 2 digits. How to do this.?
 For Example, typing in 12345678 can be truncated to 123456 on clicking RETURN key.. 
Same way,
 12345678.75 -> 123456
 123456.456 -> 123456.46

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
double input = 123456.4645;
double output;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf", input];
int dotPosition = [string rangeOfString:@"."].location;
if(dotPosition == NSNotFound || dotPosition > 6)
{
    output = [string substringToIndex:6].doubleValue;
}
else
{
    double Rate_int = [input doubleValue];

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

    NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:Rate_int]];

    output = [numberString doubleValue];

}
```

Comment: this code will not work. ouput is double and numberString is string. input is double too. pay more attention when copy / paste other solution.

Comment: strange how the answer is accepted.But there are errors on above code base.First one input is double type.And there is a method as [input doubleValue].

Answer (score 3):

This code should help.

```
double input = 12345678.75;
double output;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf", input];
int dotPosition = [string rangeOfString:@"."].location;
if(dotPosition == NSNotFound || dotPosition > 6)
{
    output = [string substringToIndex:6].doubleValue;
}
else
{
    output = round(input * 100) / 100;
}
```

**UPD according to iPhoneDev's comment:**

Previous part of code takes and returns double values.

Here is code whitch deals wiht strings:

```
NSString * input = @"123456.754";
NSString * output;
int dotPosition = [input rangeOfString:@"."].location;
if(dotPosition == NSNotFound || dotPosition > 6)
{
    output = [input substringToIndex:6];
}
else
{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.decimalSeparator = @".";
    [formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    output = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(input.doubleValue)];
}
```

Comment: But the above code base returning 123456.000000.But according to question it should return 123456.

Comment: But same on both cases it is returning 123456.00000.But it should return only 123456.

Comment: I don't know how have you checked it. But second case works properly.

Comment: m checking in xcode by coping your code.And simply put an NSLog as to show output value.Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No, but I'm doing the same. Could you please provide input that you use?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37583/discussion-between-iphonedev-and-sviatoslav-yakymiv)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    NSString* proposedString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    //if there is empty string return YES
    if([proposedString length] == 0) {
        return YES;
    }

    //create inverted set for appripriate symbols
    NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789.,"] invertedSet];

    //if side symbols is trimmed by nonNumberSet - return NO
    if([proposedString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length != [proposedString length]) {
        return NO;
    }

    if([[proposedString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"."]] count] > 2) {

        return NO;
    }

    //finally check is ok, return YES
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSArray *components = [textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    // Below 6 & 2 are the range
    NSString *leftString;
    if ([[components objectAtIndex:0] length] > 6) {
        leftString = [[components objectAtIndex:0] substringToIndex:6];
    }
    NSString *rightString;
    if ([[components objectAtIndex:1] length] > 2) {
        rightString = [[components objectAtIndex:1] substringToIndex:2];
    }

    [textField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",leftString,rightString]];

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks friend. I think the second method alone would serve my need. Can u pls explain the first method.?

Comment: In the first, you can enter numbers only in the textfield and also takes only one dot(.) symbol.